# Libgdx adrewarded video admob mediation with adcolony and charboost

Tags: libgdx, admob, chartboost, adcolony

Im facing a problem that drives me crazy
i have setup a reward video on my game .

I have implemended a rewardedvideolistener and everything working as they should , as long as i use admob for my only source of reward videos.
Now i have added 2 mediation networks chartboost and ad colony.
Im able to see the video rewards but as soon as the video end im getting an error that im unable to understand how to impement

the error is the above and its the same for both adcolony and chartboost

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method onVideoCompleted(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/reward/mediation/MediationRewardedVideoAdAdapter;)V in class Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/reward/mediation/MediationRewardedVideoAdListener; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.mediation.MediationRewardedVideoAdListener' appears in /data/app/mypackage/base.apk)
at com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyAdListener.onReward(AdColonyAdListener.java:138)
at com.adcolony.sdk.l$10.run(SourceFile:947)
at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:6029)
at com.adcolony.sdk.aw.a(SourceFile:212)
at com.adcolony.sdk.l.d(SourceFile:944)
at com.adcolony.sdk.l$15.a(SourceFile:217)
at com.adcolony.sdk.ag.a(SourceFile:188)
at com.adcolony.sdk.ag$2.run(SourceFile:157)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
```

my code is this on android laucher class

```
import Intreface.AdHandler;
import Intreface.GoogleServices;
import Intreface.IntestiliadAd;
import Intreface.VideoEventListener;


public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements 
GoogleServices, RewardedVideoAdListener, AdHandler , IntestiliadAd{
private RewardedVideoAd adRewardedVideoView;
private static final String REWARDED_VIDEO_AD_UNIT_ID = 
 ".................................";
private static String TAG = "AndroidLauncher";
private static final String AD_UNIT_ID_INTERSTITIAL = 
".............................";
private static final String AD_UNIT_ID_BANNER = 
".............................";
private final int SHOW_ADS = 1;
private final int HIDE_ADS = 0;
protected AdView adView;
private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;



Handler handler = new Handler(){

@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    switch (msg.what){
        case SHOW_ADS:
            adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case HIDE_ADS:
            adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;

    }
}
};


private boolean is_video_ad_loaded;
private VideoEventListener vel;
private MediationAdapter mediationAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new 
AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
View gameView = initializeForView(new Farbbit(this,this,this), config);
layout.addView(gameView);
setupRewarded();

interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        super.onAdLoaded();
        Log.i(TAG, "Ad loaded...");
    }
});

adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID_BANNER);
interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID_INTERSTITIAL);

interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

@Override
public void onAdLoaded() {

             }
@Override
 public void onAdClosed() {
           }
});



AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
layout.addView(adView ,adParams);

adView.loadAd(builder.build());
setContentView(layout);

}
@Override
public void showOrLoadInterstital() {
    try {
          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
                      if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                            interstitialAd.show();

                          }
                      else {
                            AdRequest interstitialRequest = new 
AdRequest.Builder().build();
                           interstitialAd.loadAd(interstitialRequest);

                          }
                    }
 });
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
  }

 @Override
  public void loadInterstital() {
  try {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
  if (!interstitialAd.isLoaded()){
    AdRequest interstitialRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    interstitialAd.loadAd(interstitialRequest);
}
}   });
} catch (Exception e) {
}
}

public void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
adRewardedVideoView.loadAd(REWARDED_VIDEO_AD_UNIT_ID, new 
AdRequest.Builder().build());
}

public void setupRewarded() {
adRewardedVideoView = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
adRewardedVideoView.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
loadRewardedVideoAd();
}


public boolean hasVideoLoaded() {
if (is_video_ad_loaded) {
    return true;
}
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (!adRewardedVideoView.isLoaded()) {
            loadRewardedVideoAd();
        }
    }
});
return false;
}

public void showRewardedVideoAd() {
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (adRewardedVideoView.isLoaded()) {
            adRewardedVideoView.show();
        } else {
            loadRewardedVideoAd();
        }
    }
});
}

@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem reward) {
 if (vel != null) {

    vel.onRewardedEvent(reward.getType(), reward.getAmount());
}
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {

}
@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {

}


@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
is_video_ad_loaded = false;
loadRewardedVideoAd();
if (vel != null) {
    vel.onRewardedVideoAdClosedEvent();
}
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
if (vel != null) {
    vel.onRewardedVideoAdLoadedEvent();
}
is_video_ad_loaded = true;
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {

}

public void setVideoEventListener(VideoEventListener listener) {
this.vel = listener;
}

@Override
public void showAds(boolean show) {
  handler.sendEmptyMessage(show ? SHOW_ADS : HIDE_ADS);
}


}
```